# Mysql - Show Rows Group by Month Date

Tags: mysql

I have a table with posts and I would like to get the data sorted by Month and Year, with all row data showing. For example, if a month has 10 rows, they should all be visible.

For post counting, I currently use this query:

```
SELECT  YEAR(created_at), MONTHNAME(created_at) ,Count(id)
FROM `posts` 
GROUP BY YEAR(created_at),MONTH(created_at);
```

Which results in:

```
2013    November    4
2013    December    5
2014    January     2
2014    February    1
2014    March   1
2014    November    15
```

However, I instead want to have the following as my output:

```
2013 November Some Post
2013 November Some Other Post
2013 December Some Other Post 2
2014 January First Post
2014 January Second Post
```

Comment: Where does the text `Some Post` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually want to use `GROUP BY`!

Instead, you want to use `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT  YEAR(created_at), MONTHNAME(created_at), name
FROM `posts` 
ORDER BY YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at);
```

I've assumed your post's names are in the `name` column.

Comment: Wooooow, thats quick @JakeSteam and thanks, this did the work. i did tried ORDER BY, but mysql was throwing error , cause i was using the GROUP BY as well in query.

Comment: Yeah, using both causes issues. You don't actually want to group by, since you want multiple per month! Make sure to mark your question as resolved if it is :)